# Why does Ava do that to Caleb?

Tags: ex-machina

At the end of *Ex Machina* Caleb is left imprisoned in Nathan's isolated villa and, without any possibility to call outside, he is doomed to death.
Ava decides to do so, deliberatingly causing Caleb to die, despite he helped her to escape and he is in love with her.
Why?